# Django. CSS. HTML. Как, нажав на изображение, загрузить на сервер другое изображение. Стилизация FileField

Tags: html, css, jquery, django

*Я только начинаю познавать Django, поэтому прошу потерпеть меня)*

У меня есть такая форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел, чтобы все надписи спрятались и, нажимая на изображение, я мог бы загрузить свою аватарку.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нужно добавить такой скрипт**

```
<script>
        function pro1(){
            document.getElementById("<id вашей формы>").click();
        }
</script>
```

**Функцию созданную выше пихаем в тэг img:**

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ user.avatar.url }}" id="image_file" onclick = "pro1()">
```

В css прячем форму:

```
.id вашей формы{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```